# Is there posibility to "debug" tikz/pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

Everybody knows that paintings with tikz/pgf is utter pain because you have to remember each dot coordinates by heart, is not there some debug or tool/tip to make life with it easier? Otherwise I spend hours for some difficult curves and graphs

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not one of those "everybody"

Comment: You do know that you can define coordinates and reuse them (by name) as well as plot graphs by a function/data points from a file, don't you?

Comment: I have to join the chorus: tikz is an incredibly powerful and well-built package. If you have having trouble with these aspects of then you are using it the wrong way.

Comment: Have you had a look at the manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)? *"The wealth of options offered by
TikZ is often **daunting to beginners**; but fortunately this documentation comes with a number **slowly-paced
tutorials** that will teach you almost all you should know about TikZ without your having to read the rest."*  **I also have problems** with TikZ from time to time. But this is almost always due to impatience (e. g. meeting a deadline in combination with using a specific TikZ feature the first time).

Comment: If you did have to specify them manually, that would surely be a huge pain, but you would hardly have to learn them by heart. But, again, despite not having to learn them by rote, there's definitely something less than optimal about your approach.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)]